# C# Speech Synthesis

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I have an application that reads a text file into byte array, 
then I convert this array to string and send it as an input to the speak method of
the SpeechSynthesizer but the SPEAK method doen't speak..

if I just send a regular temp string it works fine.. but when I convert the 
byte array to string it doesn't work.

what I did is when I read the line from the text file I use this lines of code

```
UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
string whatToSay = temp.getString(b);
speech.Speak(whatToSay); // it doesn't work even though the above line returns the  
                            correct string
```

so I wonder what is the difference if I write just this:

```
spech.Speak("hello"); // this works perfect
```

is there any difference between those strings? the speak method doesn't get UTF8 ?

Comment: Did you try round tripping (playing a string and then converting that to bytes and converting those bytes back to string and try playing it) a string to see if there is an issue with UTF-8?

Comment: no, but i'll try that

Comment: @sthotakura I did what you suggested and it works..

Comment: So, it's not UTF-8 causing problems for you, but your source of input data. It may be giving data in a different format

Comment: the problem was solved .. I used FileStream for the file instead of StreamReader.. the StreamReader solve the problem. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't see any problem with your code but maybe your variable b is something different. I am not sure what is wrong but you can also try saving the audio file somewhere and checking it if it is playing something or not:

```
 using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer()) {
     synth.SetOutputToWaveFile(@"C:\temp\Sample.wav");
     PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
     builder.AppendText("Hello World !"); //You can send a variable here also.
     synth.Speak(builder); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the variable b is the byte array which is the buffer that save what I read from the text file.

Comment: Probably you are sending inappropriate values from that text file. You should parse the text to remove the illegal characters for the SpeechSynthesizer.

Comment: the problem was solved .. I used FileStream for the file instead of StreamReader.. the StreamReader solve the problem. thanks anyway. +1